# Can this LINQ lambda expression be written any better?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linqpad

For the sake of knowledge, I wanted to convert a SQL query to a LINQ query expression.
Here is the original SQL:

```sql
SELECT CT.COURSE_NODE_ID AS CNID, CT.NODE_TEXT
FROM    COURSE_RELATED_VERSIONS AS CRV INNER JOIN
        COURSE_TREE AS CT ON CRV.COURSE_NODE_ID = CT.COURSE_NODE_ID
WHERE (CRV.COURSE_ID = '38890') AND (CRV.COURSE_PARENT_NODE_ID = '-1')
```

Basically, just grabbing two fields from a table based on certain criteria (keys match, course ID matches criteria, parent node not equal -1).
Here's the LINQ query expression that I came up with, using LINQPad:

```cs
from ct in COURSE_TREEs
join crv in COURSE_RELATED_VERSIONS 
     on ct.COURSE_NODE_ID equals crv.COURSE_NODE_ID
where crv.COURSE_ID == 38890 && crv.COURSE_PARENT_NODE_ID == -1
select new {ct.COURSE_NODE_ID, ct.NODE_TEXT}
```

Not too bad, still understandable to my SQL-centric brain.  But, for grins, I wondered what this query expression would look like as a lambda expression.  For the life of me, I could not figure out the syntax.  So, I used the lambda tool in LINQPad to see what my LINQ query expression would look like.  Here it is:

```cs
COURSE_TREEs
.Join (
   COURSE_RELATED_VERSIONS, 
   ct => ct.COURSE_NODE_ID, 
   crv => crv.COURSE_NODE_ID, 
   (ct, crv) => 
      new  
      {
         ct = ct, 
         crv = crv
      }
)
.Where (temp0 => ((temp0.crv.COURSE_ID == 38890) && (temp0.crv.COURSE_PARENT_NODE_ID ==  -1)))
.Select (
   temp0 => 
      new  
      {
         COURSE_NODE_ID = temp0.ct.COURSE_NODE_ID, 
         NODE_TEXT = temp0.ct.NODE_TEXT
      }
)
```

Whoah!  Not what I figured the lambda expression query would look like.  So, I'm studying the output from LINQPad on how my query expression looks as a lambda expression, and I'm wondering if it can be written any better?  I'm still learning the ropes of LINQ (and lambda expressions), but I can't help but feel that the resulting lambda expression here is too complex!  Am I wrong?  Is it possible to write a lambda expression that produces the same output as the original SQL and query expression, but not be needlessly complex?  Perhaps 'complex' is subjective, since it may only appear complex to my SQL brain.  I just feel like the lambda expression generated in LINQPad can be written better... I just don't know how.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Whoah!  Had no idea that existed.  Should I delete the question here, then post it at codereview?

Comment: That's up to you. But I think codereview is a more appropriate place for this question

Comment: I think most of the problems you have with that query are a result of problems with the variable names and the use of whitespace.  The query itself looks just fine to me, but it could use a fair bit of refactoring in ways that wouldn't change it's compiled code in the slightest.  That particular query (more so than many) simply fits better in a query syntax style over a method syntax style, so there's nothing wrong with using that.  Method syntax tends to simply look cleaner for different types of queries.

Comment: Do you need to use a **manual** join in your query syntax? Lambda would be cleaner if the relationships can be inferred from the database structure.

Comment: @sgmoore is correct. One of the biggest mistakes that LINQ rookies make is to use manual joins instead of querying through associations. See 'Associations' in this article: http://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx

Comment: Using the above comments, I've added a database context to my code (via dbml) and now have no need for the join at all.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler translates the query comprehension syntax in your original query to something very much like what LinqPad spit out. Those are the actual methods that are called.

If you're using a `Join`, this is as simple as it gets. If you look at the method signatures of `Join`, `Where`, and `Select`, you should hopefully be able to figure out what each part is doing and why it's doing it that way. When you break it down, you should see this isn't actually any more complicated than your original query, its just rewritten to use method calls.